# How to delete first user (admin)

Tags: 8, users, security

For security reason, I want to delete the first user (which has all rights, event without the admin role) and login only with the `drush uli` command. How can I do that? From the backoffice it say I can't remove that user

Comment: it's not possible but if you insist that, just need to delete it on database manually, go to users table and remove the user with uid =1 :|

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt that's possible, or at least not without messing with a lot of core code.

User 1 is synonymous with the root user in linux. It can be disabled, hardened, made virtually impossible to access, but not removed.

See [Securing user #1](https://www.drupal.org/node/947312) for more information.